# Mirroring an iPad to a Samsung HDTV

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad 2 which I would like to mirror NBC Sports Live Extra to my Samsung TV. My cable provider, Verizon Fios Quantum (New York City), does not carry the channel but allows subscribers to access it online using their Fios account. I, like many others, are hoping that Apple will announce a brand-new 2015 Apple TV at tomorrow's (3/9/2015) press conference or in the very near future. Until then, other than using a variety of cables and adapters or devices such as Roku 3, is there any way to mirror my iPad? Would Chromecast do the job? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to give you such a short answer, but: no.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear but I expected it! Thank you Kevin for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the answer to the same question, by direct screen mirror. So it seems like the answer is no... but there are some indirect methods:

1. Use an Apple TV and stream to it, and with the Apple TV output to the Samsung TV.
2. Use a USB cable to stream to QuickTime on a Mac, or use Airshou or AirServer to do it. Then, output the Mac's screen to the Samsung TV by an 
   HDMI cable.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a dated question, but a few things have changed since it was asked.  Many apps on iOS now support Chromecast, and this includes the NBCSn app. The NBCSN app supports Airplay to AppleTV, and Chromecast, to Chromecast dongles and TVs.

Comment: what about just a generic stream? (stream everything on the iPhone to TV)

Comment: This is possible with Airplay, where you can simply mirror your iPhone to an Apple TV. However, the iPhone does not support Chromecast directly, so each app providing the stream needs to support Chromecast.